# What do "resonate with" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

> Modi’s defence of demonetisation in Parliament fails to **resonate with** Opposition.

See the link 
http://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/modi-s-defence-of-demonetisation-in-parliament-fails-to-resonate-with-opposition/story-Y1V0VKpVC74DOQRviLx7IO.html

What do the words "resonate with" mean in this sentence? Do they mean "satisfy"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an idea resonates with its audience, then **it has been well-received by** them. A related idiom is to say that the message **struck a chord with** them.

Most (all?) materials have a resonant frequency; when a sustained sound wave of that frequency interacts with that material, the material will begin to vibrate at the same frequency. Applying that same concept to a spoken message and an audience, when the message resonates, the audience will be especially receptive to that message, and may be more likely to enthusiastically echo key points back to the speaker, or repeat it to others in the near future.

Comment: Excellent answer! Sometimes, answers are so great that you would never forget them in your lifetime. Yours is just that. Had I been a teacher taking your test as a student, I would not have hesitated in giving you 100 out of 100 marks. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[resonate with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/resonate+with)
resonate with someone

> Fig. [for an idea, issue, or concept] to appeal to someone or cause
>   someone to relate to it.